# Saving multiple Keras models in web application

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a web application to serve Keras models using Flask.
The problem when I try to launch multiple clients to train different models at the same time the app couldn't save them all on the disk ("model.h5" files).
I think it's an issue of Tensorflow graph initialization but I am not sure.
This is my route function of "/train" :

```
#http://localhost:5000/train?owner=person&id=1&train_dir=faces_train
@app.route("/train", methods=["GET"])
def train():
    if flask.request.method == "GET":
        # Arguments
        OWNER = flask.request.args.get('owner')
        ID_NEURAL_convnet = flask.request.args.get('id')
        TRAIN_DIR = flask.request.args.get('train_dir')
        MODEL_NAME = OWNER + "." + ID_NEURAL_convnet

        # Creating the dictionary of labels
        global labels_dict
        labels_dict = label_vocabulary(TRAIN_DIR)
        np.save(MODEL_NAME+'.npy', labels_dict)

        NB_CLASSES = len(labels_dict)

        # Creating train data
        train_X,train_Y = create_train_data(TRAIN_DIR)

        train_X = np.array(train_X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE, 1)
        train_X = train_X.astype('float32')
        train_X = train_X / 255.


        # Change the labels from categorical to one-hot encoding
        train_Y_one_hot = to_categorical(train_Y)

        # Split the training set in validation and training data 
        train_X,valid_X,train_label,valid_label = train_test_split(train_X, train_Y_one_hot, 
                                                                   test_size=0.2, random_state=13)
        # Building the model


        global model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(12, 12),activation='linear',padding='same',input_shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (6, 6), activation='linear',padding='same'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.4))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation='linear'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))           
        model.add(Dropout(0.3))
        model.add(Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
                          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

        model_dropout =  model.fit(train_X, train_label, batch_size=64,
                                                  epochs=2,verbose=1,validation_data=(valid_X, valid_label))

        global graph
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()

        model.save(MODEL_NAME+".h5")

        accuracy = model_dropout.history['acc']

        # Create JSON output
        result = {}
        result['accuracy'] = float(accuracy[len(accuracy)-1])
        result['nbClasses'] = NB_CLASSES

    return flask.jsonify(result)
```

For example I launched 2 clients, the first give me an error and the second is saved correctly.
This is the error:

```
[2018-08-19 17:31:12,827] ERROR in app: Exception on /save [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "server.py", line 165, in save
    globals()['model-{}'.format(MODEL_NAME)].save(MODEL_NAME+".h5")
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1104, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 122, in save_model
    save_weights_to_hdf5_group(model_weights_group, model_layers)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 449, in save_weights_to_hdf5_group
    weight_values = K.batch_get_value(symbolic_weights)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2385, in batch_get_value
    return get_session().run(ops)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d_1/bias
     [[Node: _retval_conv2d_1/bias_0_0 = _Retval[T=DT_FLOAT, index=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](conv2d_1/bias)]]
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2018 17:31:12] "GET /save?owner=ahmed&id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any ideas please !!!

Comment: Have you tried marking model and graph as not being global? If you are running concurrent instances, it is possible they will mess with each others' state.

Comment: Yes I tried this , unfortunately the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution because it works for me.
I had to make a Tensorflow session for each model I create(ie a Tensorflow graph).
This is how the server can create multiple models simultaneously.
You can refer to this issue :
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8538#issuecomment-358720718